# jQquery - the elements first class was changed, but jquery still calls the elements first class.

Tags: jquery, class, toggleclass

I have a problem and I really searched for answers and I asked some persons.. but no solution.
I have 3 'td' elements, they all belong to a class = "moreSpace" ... so when I click on a td element.. it changes its class to "deactivateAssignments" ... but the $(".moreSpace").mouseOver/mouseOut functions still have an effect on the element which its class was changed.. Why? please help me :(

(sorry for this mess, it is the first time that I post a problem here)

```
//DG

$(".moreSpace").mouseover(function(event) {
    var id = event.target.id;
    $('#'+id).css('color','#B5EABC')
});

$(".moreSpace").mouseout(function(event) {
    var id = event.target.id;
    $('#'+id).css('color','#24C635')
});

 function reclass(){
  $('#dg306').attr('class','moreSpace');
  $('#dg632').attr('class','moreSpace');
  $('#dg291').attr('class','moreSpace');
  alert('in');
```

}

```
var actId = 2;
$(".moreSpace").click(function(event) {
  reclass();
  var id = event.target.id;
  if (id == 'dg306'){
     actId = 1;
  } else if (id == 'dg632'){
     actId = 2;
  }else if (id == 'dg291'){
     actId = 3;
  }



switch (actId) {
       case 1:
            $('#dg306').toggleClass('moreSpace deactivateAssignments');
            break;
       case 2:
            $('#dg632').toggleClass('moreSpace deactivateAssignments');
            break;
       case 3:
            $('#dg291').toggleClass('moreSpace deactivateAssignments');
            break;

  }
```

Comment: you should use delegation

Comment: event handlers are attached to the elements that match the selector at the time they are attached, changing the elements class etc. later won't remove the event handlers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using direct binding on the element. So whatever you are changing on this element, the binding will still be there.

2 solutions. You can unbind the binding with `off` inside the mouse event :

```
$(this).off('mouseover mouseout');
```

Or use delegation :

```
$(document).on({
    mouseover : function(){},
    mouseout : function(){}
}, '.moreSpace');
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using $('#'+id).css('color','#24C635') to change the colour of your element, use the CSS :hover property

```
.moreSpace{
color:#24C635;
}

.moreSpace:hover{
color:#B5EABC;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check to see if the class is present in the event handler and simple return if it isn't like this

```
$(".moreSpace").mouseover(function(event) {
    if(!this.hassClass(".moreSpace") 
       return; 

    var id = event.target.id;
    $('#'+id).css('color','#B5EABC')
});
```